# Questions about Salesforce Events

Tags: discussion

I'm at Dreamforce, and found myself wondering "I wonder when session videos will be posted... I bet someone at SFSE knows!  but that's probably off-topic for the site..."

What do you think?  More generally, should our scope just be about **using** Salesforce, or also about the formal (and informal?) Salesforce ecosystem?

I think I lean towards "just using the platform", but wanted to bring it up here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that your question (And any other time sensitive query) Is best asked via the Salesforce chat room rather than on the main site.

If you word the question to be less time sensitive i.e: "Where can I find session videos from Dreamforce?" Would be valid (If not showing a slight lack of prior research)

Comment: Argh just reread the last bit of my answer and realised it sounds quiet snarky! It honestly isn't :)